# how to solve a cubic congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have to solve this congruence: $x^3 \equiv 1\,(\mod\;101)$ , but I I can't understand some steps,
$$
x^3 \equiv 1\,(\mod\;101) \\
\gcd(3,100)=1\\
3a+100b=1\\
x^1\equiv x^{3a+100b} \equiv1^a\cdot1^b\equiv 1\;(\mod\;101)
$$
Solution:$x \equiv 1 \;(\mod\;101)$

In particular, I don't understand what the $3$ of the greatest common divisor represents(is it the exponent?) and why $x^{3a+100b}$ is equivalent to $1^a\cdot1^b$.

Comment: By *3 of the greatest divisor* do you mean $\gcd(3,100)$?

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the $3$ in $\gcd(3,100)=1$ is the exponent in the equation (which is a *cubic* equation b.t.w.).

As to $x^{3a+100b}$, it is equal to $x^{3a}x^{100b}=(x^3)^a(x^{100})^b=1^a(x^{100})^b$, and $x^{100}\equiv 1\bmod 101$ by *lil' Fermat*, since $101$ is prime.

Comment: I still can't understand why $x^3=1$

Comment: Simply that's what you're supposed to solve,  so they try to see what can be deduced from this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

$101$ is prime, so the nonzero residues modulo $101$ form a cyclic group of order $100$ (under multiplication modulo $101$). Since $\gcd(3,100)=1$ it follows that the map that takes $x$ to $x^3$ is one-one and onto, so $x^3\equiv1\bmod{101}$ has exactly one solution. Since $x=1$ is obviously a solution, it is the only solution.